# Убрать все элементы на странице с классом

Tags: javascript, css

Мне нужно убрать все элементы на странице с **классом** *user*

(Изменить свойство *display* на *none*).

Как это сделать на чистом JS, без использования сторонних библиотек?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var elems=document.getElementsByClassName('user');
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++)elems[i].style.display='none';
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно! Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

Если браузер не совсем древний, то для обхода коллекции можно использовать `Array.forEach` и сделать так:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('user'), function(item) { 
    item.style.display = 'none';
});
```